# Do I need to install wxWidget library separately when I download the wxFormbuilder?

Tags: wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I have recently started GUI development using wxwidget using `C++` and `MinGW`.

Do I need to install `wxWidget` library separately when I download the `wxFormbuilder`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need wxwidgets installed to work with formbuilder. I suggest you to install codeblocks with mingw which you can find http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26  and follow this link https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/CodeBlocks_Setup_Guide to compling wxwidgets. When you are installing formbuilder for the first I guess it will ask for the location of wxwidgets installed directory so you need to have this or else you can setup this later.

Let me know if you have queries